# Cannot connect plant's state_output_port with WsgController's state_input_port

Tags: drake

I was trying to change `MakeManipulationStation` to adapt my own settings. I didn't the change the part that add Iiwa and Wsg. However, when configuring Wsg (connecting ports), I got an error.

```
RuntimeError: InputPort::Eval(): required InputPort[0] (u0) of System ::_::wsg1_controller::drake/systems/StateInterpolatorWithDiscreteDerivative@0000562a7a82aa10::drake/systems/Multiplexer@0000562a7aaa90c0 (Multiplexer<double>) is not connected
```

The function I configure Wsg is:

```
def ConfigureWsg(builder, plant, wsg, name='wsg', time_step=0.002):
    # Add wsg controller
    wsg_controller = builder.AddSystem(SchunkWsgPositionController(time_step=time_step))
    wsg_controller.set_name(f"{name}_controller")
    builder.Connect(wsg_controller.get_generalized_force_output_port(),
                    plant.get_actuation_input_port(wsg))
    builder.Connect(plant.get_state_output_port(wsg),
                    wsg_controller.get_state_input_port())
    builder.ExportInput(wsg_controller.get_desired_position_input_port(),
                        f"{name}_position")
    builder.ExportInput(wsg_controller.get_force_limit_input_port(),
                        f"{name}_force_limit")
    wsg_mbp_state_to_wsg_state = builder.AddSystem(
        MakeMultibodyStateToWsgStateSystem())
    builder.Connect(plant.get_state_output_port(wsg),
                    wsg_mbp_state_to_wsg_state.get_input_port())
    builder.ExportOutput(wsg_mbp_state_to_wsg_state.get_output_port(),
                         f"{name}_state_measured")
    builder.ExportOutput(wsg_controller.get_grip_force_output_port(),
                         f"{name}_force_measured")
```

which I think is the same as how `MakeManipulationStation` configuring Wsg.

I think this line:

```
builder.Connect(plant.get_state_output_port(wsg),
                wsg_controller.get_state_input_port())
```

should connect the plant's state_output_port with wsg_controller's state_input_port. I don't understand why I still get this error?

Comment: I agree that the Connect line looks it should have connected that port.  I suspect the problem is somewhere else?  Are you sure that the system/context that generates that error is being built by this code?

Comment: Actually directly use `MakeManipulationStation` gives me the same error. The way I construct is:
`file_name = FindResource("models/iiwa_and_wsg.dmd.yaml")`
`builder = DiagramBuilder()`
`station = builder.AddSystem(
    MakeManipulationStation(filename=file_name, time_step=0.001))`
Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: Running exactly those lines works fine for me using the `MakeManipulationStation` in the course repo.